# How to run a Spark-java program from command line

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

I am running the wordcount java program in spark. How do I run it from the command line.

Comment: Did you check this: https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Answer (score 3):

Pick up the wordcount example from say: https://github.com/holdenk/fastdataprocessingwithsparkexamples/tree/master/src/main/scala/pandaspark/examples. 
Follow these steps to create the fat jar file:

```
mkdir example-java-build/; cd example-java-build

mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
   -DgroupId=spark.examples \
   -DartifactId=JavaWordCount \
   -Dfilter=org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart

cp ../examples/src/main/java/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java
JavaWordCount/src/main/java/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java
```

You add the relevant spark-core and spark examples dependencies. Make sure you have the dependencies based on your version of spark.  I use spark 1.1.0 and so I have the relevant dependencies.
  My pom.xml looks like this:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-examples_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Build your jar file using mvn.

```
cd example-java-build/JavaWordCount
mvn package
```

This creates your fat jar file inside the target directory.
Copy the jar file to any location on the server.
Go to the your bin folder of your spark. ( in my case: `/root/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin`)

Submit spark job: My job looks like this:

```
./spark-submit --class "spark.examples.JavaWordCount" --master yarn://myserver1:8032 /root/JavaWordCount-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  hdfs://myserver1:8020/user/root/hackrfoe.txt
```

Here --class is: The entry point for your application (e.g. org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi)
--master: The master URL for the cluster (e.g. spark://23.195.26.187:7077)
The last argument is any text file of your choice for the program.

The output should like this, giving word counts of all words in the text file.

```
in: 17
sleeping.: 1
sojourns: 1
What: 4
protect: 1
largest: 1
other: 1
public: 1
worst: 1
hackers: 12
detected: 1
from: 4
and,: 1
secretly: 1
breaking: 1
football: 1
answer.: 1
attempting: 2
"hacker: 3
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Well documented answer. I haven't tried it yet but even if it has any small bugs it will be helpful. I will report back if any details missing.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to build your Java program as a standalone application using Maven (following the example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#standalone-applications)), and then [submitting your application](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) using spark-submit.